# Neural Network from scratch: cost increasing over epochs

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to design a neural network from scratch. After training my neural network, I make a plot of the cost vs epochs, which I would expect to decrease throughout the runtime of the NN training, and eventually approach a horizontal asymptote (if everything is done correctly). However, when I plot the cost, it decreases down to a point, and then increases endlessly. I must be doing something wrong, perhaps in the back propagation step? I'm having trouble spotting my error.

Here is a section of my neural_net class which contains all the functions that I call in the train function.

```py
class neural_net:
    def __init__(self, train_data, valid_data, test_data, train_labels, valid_labels, test_labels, input_dim, output_dim, neuron_nums, seed, output_function, learning_rate, epochs, et, ect):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.valid_data = valid_data
        self.test_data = test_data
        self.train_labels = train_labels
        self.valid_labels = valid_labels
        self.test_labels = test_labels
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.neuron_nums = neuron_nums
        self.seed = seed
        self.output_function = output_function
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.error_threshold = et
        self.error_ch_thres = ect

    def seed_model(self):
        w1, w_out, b1, b_out = np.zeros(4)
        np.random.seed(self.seed)    
        # now initialize the weight matrices to have random numbers that are small
        # and initialize the bias vectors to have zeros
        w1 = np.random.randn(self.neuron_nums, input_dim)*0.01
        b1 = np.zeros(shape = (self.neuron_nums, 1))
        w_out = np.random.randn(output_dim, self.neuron_nums)*0.01
        b_out = np.zeros(shape = (output_dim, 1))
        return w1, w_out, b1, b_out

    def forward_propagate(self, w1, w_out, b1, b_out, data_type):
        if data_type == "train":
            X = self.train_data
            labels = self.train_labels
        if data_type == "validate":
            X = self.valid_data
            labels = self.valid_labels
        if data_type == "test":
            X = self.test_data
            labels = self.test_labels
        X = np.transpose(X)
        z1, a1, z_out, output_prediction, cost = np.zeros(5)

        # use sigmoid for all hidden layers and then let user decide what output function is
        z1 = np.dot(w1,X) + b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z_out = np.dot(w_out,a1) + b_out
        if self.output_function == 'sigmoid':
            output_prediction = sigmoid(z_out)
        if self.output_function == 'linear':
            output_prediction = linear(z_out)
        if self.output_function == 'softmax':
            output_prediction = softmax(z_out)
        return z1, a1, z_out, output_prediction

    def compute_cost(self, output_prediction):
        labels = self.train_labels
        sq_errs = np.zeros(len(labels))
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            sq_errs[i] = (output_prediction.T[i] - labels[i])**2
        cost = np.sum(sq_errs) / len(labels)
        return cost

    def back_propagate(self, a1, outout_prediction, w1, w_out):
        X = self.train_data
        labels = self.train_labels
        l = len(X)
        X = np.transpose(X)

        dz_out = np.zeros_like(output_prediction.T)
        for i in range(len(output_prediction.T)):
            dz_out[i] = (output_prediction.T[i] - train_labels[i])
        dz_out = np.transpose(dz_out)
        dw_out = (1/l) * np.dot(dz_out, a1.T)
        db_out = (1/l) * np.sum(dz_out, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        dz1 = np.multiply(np.dot(w_out.T, dz_out), 1-np.power(a1,2))
        dw1 = (1/l) * np.dot(dz1, X.T)
        db1 = (1/l) * np.sum(dz1, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        return dw_out, db_out, dw1, db1

    def update_parameters(self, w1, w_out, b1, b_out, dw1, dw_out, db1, db_out):
        lr = self.learning_rate
        w1 = w1 - lr*dw1
        b1 = b1 - lr*db1
        w_out = w_out - lr*dw_out
        b_out = b_out - lr*db_out
        return w1, w_out, b1, b_out

    def train(self):
        ep = 0
        w1, w_out, b1, b_out = neural_net.seed_model(self)
        cost = 10000000
        costs = [0]
        cost_change = 1000000

        # create initial w's and b's with seed_model(), then loop the following until any of the stop condition are met:
            # forward_propagate to predict the output with the current model, evaluate the cost and cost change,
            # then back_propagate to get dw's and db's, and finally update the w's and b's with update_parameters
        while cost > self.error_threshold and ep < self.epochs and cost_change > self.error_ch_thres:
            z1, a1, z_out, output_prediction= neural_net.forward_propagate(self,w1, w_out, b1, b_out, data_type = "train")
            cost = NN.compute_cost(output_prediction)
            costs.append(cost)
            cost_change = np.absolute(costs[-1] - costs[-2])
            dw_out, db_out, dw1, db1 = neural_net.back_propagate(self,a1, output_prediction, w1, w_out)
            w1, w_out, b1, b_out = neural_net.update_parameters(self,w1, w_out, b1, b_out, dw1, dw_out, db1, db_out)
            ep += 1
        # create plot of cost vs epochs so we can visualize when the network should stop training
        plt.plot(costs[1:])
        plt.title("cost vs epochs")
        return w1, w_out, b1, b_out
```

For more clarity, my training dataset has 57 features and 2300 examples.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope the code is not too junky, I'm not a master of python.